# Get Azure SQL table size by month

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have Azure SQL DB and need to get size of each table by month wise. I have a query which will give entire size of tables, but how can I extract the size of table by month wise?

Query to get size of table:

```
SELECT 
t.NAME AS TableName,
s.Name AS SchemaName,
p.rows,
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS 
NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS TotalSpaceMB,
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024.00), 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 
2)) AS UsedSpaceMB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB,
CAST(ROUND(((SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8) / 
1024.00, 2) AS NUMERIC(36, 2)) AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = 
p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
TotalSpaceMB DESC, t.Name
```

Comment: Cross-site duplicate candidate: [How do i know a table size and row counts for each month, for the past six months?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191321/how-do-i-know-a-table-size-and-row-counts-for-each-month-for-the-past-six-month)

Comment: TL;DR: Unless you are monitoring the growth, you don't know. The fact that you are asking its question means that you likely aren't (as if you were, you wouldn't be asking this question, and where you're storing the information would be proprietary).

Comment: unless you actually partition per month, there are no exact ways of tracking the space usage per rows. But nothing stops you from doing some kind of estimation: totalSize / numberOfMonth

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thom A and siggemannen
The size of each table is  partitioned by year and month, ordered by partition year, partition month, and table size in descending order
I did  research and followed the same approach the query gives size of each table by month wise.

I have queried to get the size of the tables.

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS table_name,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS table_size_kb
FROM 
    sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
GROUP BY 
    t.name
ORDER BY 
    table_size_kb DESC;
```

[image]

You can try this below query that partition_year and
partition_month

```
SELECT
    t.name AS table_name,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS table_size_kb,
    DATEPART(YEAR, p.partition_number) AS partition_year,
    DATEPART(MONTH, p.partition_number) AS partition_month
FROM
    sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON i.object_id = p.object_id AND i.index_id = p.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
GROUP BY
    t.name,
    DATEPART(YEAR, p.partition_number),
    DATEPART(MONTH, p.partition_number)
ORDER BY
    partition_year,
    partition_month,
    table_size_kb DESC;
```

[image]

[image]